# Clustering data with different approaches

Tags: cluster-analysis

i have the following type of data:

*.edge file has the connections between ids of different users:

1 23

4 67

...

*.feat contains properties of the ids. Here the first column (column 0) are the userids. The other ones are representing features named in another file. For example userid 1 does not have the feature of column 1 (0), but userid 4 does (1):

1: 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1

4: 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1

...

Now i want to cluster the data and want to use different algorithms like k-means, DBSCAN, hierarchical clustering  and so on. But as i read, there are several problems with multidimensional data?

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with very high-dimensional data, but 10 is not high. You have other problems: k-means needs *coordinates* to compute means, not a graph with edges. Also, the values should be continuous, not binary. You need to study these methods in more detail. If you say "But as I read ...", then try to give a reference.

Comment: this is exactly the problem i also have. My intention is to cluster friends in Facebook for a particular user and using different clustering algorithms for this purpose. However i do not know where to start. Thought the data from stanford would be good for that (https://snap.stanford.edu/data/egonets-Facebook.html)

Comment: Read up on graph algorithms such as clique detection, not point clustering like kmeans. Users aren't vectors.

Comment: Considering only the edges. How about using a graph algorithm and then extract the X and Y coordinates to use algorithms like K-Means?

Comment: Don't hack just to make a function *callable*. Think about the question to answer, not how to glue together tools that don't match.